# Codeigniter 4 , running error

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am testing CodeIgniter 4, but I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL in C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter4-develop\system\Config\DotEnv.php on line 121

What am I missing?

Comment: It is only a alpha version not ready yet still in development https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter4

Comment: So what's your code? The message is about some class hint where a default value of a param is not `NULL`, we probably can't say more from the message only.

Comment: I would suggest posting issue on here https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter4/issues/new

Comment: @wolfgang1983 OP should do some basic debugging first

Answer (score 1):

You Need **PHP7** for **codeigniter4**.

If you need to test it you can even use any free hosting server like **000webhosting** as i used.

Secondly download **latest code** from ci4 website now its refined.

Answer (score 0):

Update your PHP Version to PHP7.

I was also encountered with this error but finally got the answer on Codeigniter Forum.

http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-65773.html

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter 4 requires php 7.

Verifying that, and then making sure CI works with a clean install from the git repo. Once you see the welcome page then you're good to go. If you are having issues with your own code, then please post that on here. Or post in the repo if you have found a bug in CI4.

> *Refer to the Documentation:*
>
> PHP version 7.0 or newer is required.
>
> https://bcit-ci.github.io/CodeIgniter4/intro/requirements.html
>
> *Current GitHub Repo:*
>
> https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter4